# Returning a arraylist variable from a method in java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, return

```
 public ArrayList<detailTom>  read() 
{
   try 
   {
       /*System.out.println("Hello");*/
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G:/sample.txt"));
       String data;
       ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<String> tomList= new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<detailTom> tomData = new ArrayList<detailTom>();

       while((data= in.readLine())!=null)
       {
           /*System.out.println(data);*/
           String[] splits=data.split(" ");
           for(int i=0;i<splits.length;i++)
           {
                 if (splits[i].equals("tom"))
                 {
                       detailTom dummy= new detailTom();
                        dummy.name="tom";
                        dummy.mark1=Integer.parseInt(splits[1]);
                        dummy.mark2=Integer.parseInt(splits[2]);
                        dummy.mark3=Integer.parseInt(splits[3]);
                        dummy.mark4=Integer.parseInt(splits[4]);
                        dummy.mark5=Integer.parseInt(splits[5]); 

                        tomData.add(dummy);

                 }
           }

       }

   }

   catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
   {
       Logger.getLogger(MyInterface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } catch (IOException ex) 
   {
       Logger.getLogger(MyInterface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
   return tomData;


}
```

Hello!

I am trying to return a variable tomData which is an object of class ArrayList. detailTom is a class which has variables , getters , setters and so forth . What I want to do is my method read() to return tomData. But I get an error at the line return tomData.

The error says:-

cannot find symbol 
Symbol: variable tomData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tomData` is declared inside `try block`.Variables declared inside try block are not accisible outside of it.So just declare `tomData` out of `try block`.Try this

```
public ArrayList<detailTom>  read() 
{
   ArrayList<detailTom> tomData = null;
   try 
   {
       /*System.out.println("Hello");*/
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G:/sample.txt"));
       String data;
       ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<String> tomList= new ArrayList<String>();
       tomData  = new ArrayList<detailTom>();

       while((data= in.readLine())!=null)
       {
           /*System.out.println(data);*/
           String[] splits=data.split(" ");
           for(int i=0;i<splits.length;i++)
           {
                 if (splits[i].equals("tom"))
                 {
                       detailTom dummy= new detailTom();
                        dummy.name="tom";
                        dummy.mark1=Integer.parseInt(splits[1]);
                        dummy.mark2=Integer.parseInt(splits[2]);
                        dummy.mark3=Integer.parseInt(splits[3]);
                        dummy.mark4=Integer.parseInt(splits[4]);
                        dummy.mark5=Integer.parseInt(splits[5]); 

                        tomData.add(dummy);

                 }
           }

       }

   }

   catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
   {
       Logger.getLogger(MyInterface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } catch (IOException ex) 
   {
       Logger.getLogger(MyInterface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
   return tomData;


}
```

Answer (score 5):

You've declared `tomData` inside your `try`-block, so it isn't visible outside. Try moving the declaration before the `try`-block.

```
ArrayList<DetailTom> tomData;

try {
    ...
    tomData = ...
```

Also note that I've assumed a more standard naming convention: class names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: thanks for your comment - But i initialized tomData outside the try block. That worked!!

Comment: You'll need to initialise `tomData` to something for this to work - otherwise it won't compile as `tomData` may not have been initialised.

Answer (score 4):

`tomData` is out of scope when you're trying to return it. There's a number of ways around this, but the easiest would be to declare and initialise `tomData` *before* the `try` block.

Answer (score 3):

Your return tomData at the bottom occurs outside of the try block where tomData was declared, so it is out of scope, try declare tomData at the top of the method